# angular ng-repeat through multi level object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object that has different objects within in, here is an example of the object

```
{  
   "0":{  
      "name":{  
         "type":"unchanged",
         "data":"HV010BSML"
      },
      "colour":{  
         "type":"unchanged",
         "data":"BLACK"
      },
      "size":{  
         "type":"unchanged",
         "data":"SML"
      },
      "qty":{  
         "type":"unchanged",
         "data":1
      },
      "localimg":{  
         "type":"unchanged",
         "data":"/data/New%20Products/HV010%20Black%20with%20pocket%20WM-700x700.jpg"
      },
      "sml":{  
         "type":"unchanged",
         "data":"2"
      },
      "stock":{  
         "type":"unchanged",
         "data":"78"
      },
      "id":{  
         "type":"unchanged",
         "data":"153"
      },
      "name2":{  
         "type":"unchanged",
         "data":"HV010"
      }
   },
   "1":{  
      "type":"created",
      "data":{  
         "name":"HV001YSML",
         "colour":"YELLOW",
         "size":"SML",
         "qty":1,
         "localimg":"/data/HV001-HV-VEST-YLW-700x700.jpg",
         "sml":"1",
         "stock":"424",
         "id":"8",
         "name2":"HV001"
      }
   }
}
```

Im wondering if it is possible to iterate over each of these using ng-repeat, because its an object within an object? Ive created a table with ng-repeat and in the "change" col i want to do another ng repeat (which uses the object i showed above) but when i try to show the data in the html its just printing every letter of the array. I'm basically trying to ng-repeat through the object[0] and show it in a readable format such as "HV010BSML is unchanged"

Here is my html :

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="ibox float-e-margins">

                <div class="ibox-content">
                    <table datatable="ng" dt-options="dtOptions"  class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables-example">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>User</th>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Change</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="(oIndex, o) in orderdata">
                            <td>{{o.user}}</td>
                            <td>{{o.date}}</td>
                            <td> <div ng-repeat="d in formatdata(findhistory(oIndex)) track by $index">{{d}}</div></td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In the controller, findhistory just returns that object i showed and formatdata is this function in the controller

```
$scope.formatdata=function(obj){
    try{
    if(obj[0]){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(obj[0]));
return JSON.stringify(obj[0]);
}
else{
    return;
}
}
catch(ex){}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Iterating over object properties**
>
> It is possible to get ngRepeat to iterate over the properties of an
>   object using the following syntax:
>
> ```
> <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in myObj"> ... </div>
> ```
>
> However, there are a few limitations compared to array iteration:
>
> - The JavaScript specification does not define the order of keys returned for an object, so AngularJS relies on the order returned by
>     the browser when running for key in myObj. Browsers generally follow
>     the strategy of providing keys in the order in which they were
>     defined, although there are exceptions when keys are deleted and
>     reinstated. See the MDN page on delete for more info.
> - ngRepeat will silently ignore object keys starting with $, because it's a prefix used by AngularJS for public ($) and private ($$)
>     properties.
> - The built-in filters orderBy and filter do not work with objects, and will throw an error if used with one.
>
> If you are hitting any of these limitations, the recommended
>   workaround is to convert your object into an array that is sorted into
>   the order that you prefer before providing it to ngRepeat. You could
>   do this with a filter such as toArrayFilter or implement a $watch on
>   the object yourself.

*Extracted from the [Angularjs API reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)*

Personally, i think you could benefit from a little change in your data source, instead of a object holding everything together, use a collection with some similar objects inside. It's easier to understand and has a better support with the ngRepeat.

How about something like this:

```
[  
   {
      "id": "0",
      "data": [
         {
            "property": "name",
            "type":"unchanged",
            "data":"HV010BSML"
         },
         {
            "property": "colour",
            "type":"unchanged",
            "data":"BLACK"
         },
         {
            "property": "size",
            "type":"unchanged",
            "data":"SML"
         },
         {
            "property": "qty",
            "type":"unchanged",
            "data":1
         },
         {
            "property": "localimg",
            "type":"unchanged",
            "data":"/data/New%20Products/HV010%20Black%20with%20pocket%20WM-700x700.jpg"
         },
         {
            "property": "sml",
            "type":"unchanged",
            "data":"2"
         },
         {
            "property": "stock",
            "type":"unchanged",
            "data":"78"
         },
         {
            "property": "id",
            "type":"unchanged",
            "data":"153"
         },
         {
            "property": "name2",
            "type":"unchanged",
            "data":"HV010"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "id": "1"
      "data": [
         {
            "type":"created",
            "data":{  
               "name":"HV001YSML",
               "colour":"YELLOW",
               "size":"SML",
               "qty":1,
               "localimg":"/data/HV001-HV-VEST-YLW-700x700.jpg",
               "sml":"1",
               "stock":"424",
               "id":"8",
               "name2":"HV001"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```